# How to add condition for all where query for an ActiveRecordModel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a user table in my rails application and the application uses many `where` conditions for this model throughout the application in many controller methods.

Now i have to add an extra attribute for the where condition.
is there a way to do the following and how? instead of adding the extra attribute to all the where condition used in the entire application can i write a custom `where` to the user model so the condition will be pre-added to the `where` in entire application for the user model.

i found out the source for the where

```
def where(opts = :chain, *rest)
 if :chain == opts
  WhereChain.new(spawn)
 elsif opts.blank?
  self
 else
  spawn.where!(opts, *rest)
 end
end
```

my where condition in the controller methods now:

```
User.where(:status => true, :country => "IN")
```

this condition and similar conditions are used in many methods in application and i want to get the user who has not `:deactivated`.

i can make changes to all where condition like

```
User.where(:status => true, :country => "IN", :deactivated => false)
```

instead i thought of writing a custom where that precheck `:deactivated => false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Default Scope:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope -> { where(deactivated: false) }
end
```

You can use `default_scope`.

Now, whenever you query `User`, automatically the default scope query will get appended.

For more details on `default_scope`, please refer:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-default_scope

If there are usecases that prevent you from using default_scope, then you can use custom scopes or unscope the default scope.

**Unscoping:**

You can unscope in `Project` model if you want to remove the default scope.

`belongs_to :user, ->{ unscope(where: :deactivated) }`

Or you can fetch all user and then unscope
`project.users.unscoped`

**Custom Scope:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :deactivated, ->(deactivated = false) { where(deactivated: deactivated) }
end
```

Now, to make use of that scope, you can query like this:

```
User.deactivated.where(:status => true, :country => "IN")
```

For reference:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope

Comment: I cant use `default_scope` because suppose a project belongs to a deactivated user.If we give `project.user` it won't show the result.

Comment: Updated the answer, please check

Comment: for this solution also i need to make changes to all old where conditions exist in my methods

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, these are the only two options.

Comment: adding `belongs_to :user, ->{ unscope(where: :deactivated) }` will unscope from the association , thank you for your answer, please update so i can accept the answer